# JSON formatting for downloading documents but only viewing folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm working on a SharePoint Library that has both documents and folders. I've added JSON formatting to show a "Download" button for all items. I need to change that to only download for documents.

For the Folders I'd like it to either be blank or show "Open". Is this possible?

This is what I have so far:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-...",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "Download",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "LightGrey",
    "text-decoration": "Bold",
    "color": "Black",
    "font-size": "12px",
    "padding-left": "16px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "=@currentWeb+'/_layouts/15/download.aspx?sourceurl='+[$FileRef]"
  }
}
```

Comment: I am checking the status of this case. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.
If you have any update about this issue, please feel free to post back.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the download button for folders using the "Content Type" column in the SharePoint document library.

**Example**:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "button",
    "style": {
        "border-radius": "5px",
        "margin": "5px 0px",
        "padding": "0px",
        "visibility": "=if([$ContentType] == 'Folder', 'hidden', 'visible')"
    },
    "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-bgColor-themePrimary"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "txtContent": "Download",
            "style": {
                "text-decoration": "none",
                "padding": "10px 0px",
                "width": "100%"
            },
            "attributes": {
                "href": "= @currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=' + [$UniqueId]",
                "target": "_blank",
                "class": "ms-fontColor-white"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Where below line hides the JSON button for folders:

```
"visibility": "=if([$ContentType] == 'Folder', 'hidden', 'visible')"
```

Where `[$ContentType]` and `[$UniqueId]` are internal names of Content type and Unique ID columns in SharePoint document library. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

**Reference**: [SharePoint Online: Download files using JSON Formatting](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/11/10/sharepoint-online-download-files-using-json-formatting/)

**Note**: The download functionality does not work for folder content type. So, in order to hide the download button for folders, you may have to show/include the "Content Type" column in your library view.

Comment: You can also try using `FSObjType` instead of content type. FSObjType='1' for folders and FSObjType='0' for files.